# Is it possible to have javascript ignore a specific section of my html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that executes on every page of my website.  I still want it to execute on the page in question but just to ignore a section.

E.g.

```
<p>process with javascript</p>
<p>skip, have javascript function ignore</p>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

If there is an inline tag or something that would be what i am looking for. E.g.

```
<p>process with javascript</p>
<script-ignore><p>skip, have javascript function ignore</p></script-ignore>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

Comment: This entirely depends on what your script is doing. Please include more detail in your question

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing how the script works. To get you started, if the traversal of the page ( more precisely: of the DOM built from the age html)  is selector-based, you could add a css class (eg. `script-include`) and thus skip over all elements not marked, or you add a class to elements to be skipped (eg. `script-ignore`) and test for the class attribute before processing the element. Again, for targeted help we have to inspect the script.

Comment: I like your idea, and I figured out how to implement the script-include and script-ignore idea.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**in my opinion the best way, is using `not` in the selector**

```js
$('p:not(.js-ignore)') // ignore the section by class "js-ignore"
  .css('background','blue') //whatever your code dose
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>process with javascript</p>
<p class='js-ignore'>skip, have javascript function ignore</p>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

**by your way i believe you can do something like this:**

```js
$( "p" ).each(function() {
  if(!$(this).parents('script-ignore').length){
    $(this).css('background','blue')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>process with javascript</p>
<script-ignore><p>skip, have javascript function ignore</p></script-ignore>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

## Update 1

**i realise you didn't mention 'jquery' so this is pure vanilla JS:**

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p'); // select

for( i=0; i< p.length; i++ ){
  if(p[i].parentElement.localName !== 'script-ignore'){
    // whatever your code is
   p[i].style.background = 'red'
   p[i].style.color = '#fff'
  }
}
```

```html
<p>process with javascript</p>
<script-ignore><p>skip, have javascript function ignore</p></script-ignore>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<p>process with javascript</p>
<p class="dontIncludeJavascriptCall">skip, have javascript function ignore</p>
<p>process with javascript</p>
```

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p:not(.dontIncludeJavascriptCall)");
console.log(ps);
```

This will only give you the 2 P tags which do not have that class

Comment: upvote for not using jQuery, which the OP did not tag the question as.

Answer (score 0):

Try put a class name class="useJS" in your p tag that use JavaScript.

Then point your script to .useJS class only.